# Style switcher with PHP and CSS

Tags: php, css

i have this simple style swicher

```
style.css

    body.defualt {  background-color: RGB(230,197,173);
                background-image:url("img/defualt.gif") ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat ;
                font-family : Lucida Handwriting;
                color : white;
}
body.spring {
                background-image:url("img/spring.png");
                background-repeat: repeat ;
                font-family : Arial Rounded MT Bold;

            }
body.winter{
                background-image:url("img/winter.png");
                background-repeat: repeat ;
                font-family : Comic Sans MS;
                color : RGB(53,31,99);

            }

a   {text-decoration : none;
    color :RGB(175,48,175);
    }
a:hover {text-decoration :underline ;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        }
```

now
when i change defualt style it's changed
but when make refresh it's return to defualt
i want know how to save my style

```
<?php
     if ($GLOBALS["language"]==arabic)
                            {include ("ar.php");}
                            else {include ("en.php");}

?>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>
            MultiMedia
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="function.js" > </script>
    </head>
    <body class="defualt">
            <br/><br/>
            <!-- header -->
            <!-- MultiMedia -->
            <h1 ><center><?php echo $header ; ?></center></h1>

            <!-- theme selector -->
            <table  style="position:fixed;left:25px;top:210px;" >
                    <tr> <th> <?php echo $choose?><th> <tr/>
                    <tr>
                        <td align=center>
                            <a onclick ="change('defualt');" title="Defualt" ><img src="img/defualtTHM.gif" style="border-color:white;" border=2 /> </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align=center>
                            <a onclick ="change('spring');" title="Spring" ><img src="img/springTHM.png" style="border-color:white;" border=2 /> </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align=center>
                            <a onclick ="change('winter');" title="Winter" ><img src="img/winterTHM.png" style="border-color:white;" border=2 /> </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: what does the js `change(..)` do?

Comment: `if ($GLOBALS["language"]==arabic)` should be `if ($GLOBALS['language'] == 'arabic')`!

Comment: Ok no problem about language but i need to make my new style to stay and fanction.js give notify about new style function change (theme){

document.body.className = theme;
alert (theme + " theme is on ");

}

Answer (score 2):

Keep it in the session.

If you're using PHP, send it to your controller and then store the value in your session. Next time when you load the PHP file, check your session, if the key is set, then load that CSS file otherwise load the default

switchstyle.php

```
$style = isset($_GET['style']) ? $_GET['style'] : false;
if ($style) {
   $_SESSION['custom_style'] = $style;
}
```

In index.php (assuming that's your view

```
if (isset($_SESSION['custom_style'])) {
  //load the style
} else {
  //load default style
}
```

**NOTE** This is an example/suggestion only. You should validate your $_GET and $_SESSION checks so you stay protected.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store (and set) language as a `$_SESSION` variable, not a `$_GLOBALS` variable.

For example, try this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['language'] = "arabic";
```

You can then change $_SESSION, and it'll be tracked (for that user only) across pages, as long as you call `session_start();` before you try and access or change any `$_SESSION` variable.

Answer (score 0):

it would be nice if we could see the "change" function but I guess you need this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function change(theme) {
      var date = new Date ();
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3); // this theme will stay 3 days
      document.cookie = 'theme=' + theme + '; expires=' + date.toUTCString()
   }
</script>
```

and in the html

```
<body class="<?=isset($_COOKIE['theme'])?$_COOKIE['theme']:'default'?>">
```